# How to determine all $2 \times 2$ normal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

> Determine all $2 \times 2$ normal matrices.

In particular, how would I show that there are normal matrices which are neither unitary, Hermitian, skew-Hermitian, symmetric, nor skew-symmetric. The only thing I do know is $AA^* = A^*A$, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried writing in $a,b,c,d$ as entries of $2 \times 2$ matrix, but it seemed to lead nowhere.

Comment: @hardmath But is normalization a necessary condition?

Comment: I'm suggesting it as a tactic, to discover the $2\times 2$ normal matrices in the most economical way.  For example, $A$ is normal if and only if $A- I$ is normal.  And $A$ is normal if and only if $\beta A$ is normal for some nonzero real $\beta$.  I think we can help ourselves by reframing the problem with less than the four parameters you started with.

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem for normal matrices?

Comment: Not at all. I've attended about 3 lectures on intro to linear algebra.

Comment: Ok, well that would give you one easy way to describe all normal matrices in terms of the unitary matrices. Maybe you can look it up. For the second part of the problem one approach is to think of a unitary matrix without the last four properties [try a real rotation matrix]  and then rescale it to make it non-unitary.

Comment: If you're 3 lectures into linear algebra, then why are you interested in normal matrices anyway?  Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $A$ is normal if and only if $AA^* - A^*A = 0$. If we take
$$
A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d},
$$
then [we find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D.Conjugatetranspose%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D%20-%20Conjugatetranspose%5B%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D%5D.%7B%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2Cd%7D%7D)
$$
AA^* - A^*A = 
\pmatrix{|b|^2 - |c|^2 & -b \bar a + a \bar c + b \bar d - d \bar c\\
\overline{-b \bar a + a \bar c + b \bar d - d \bar c} & |c|^2 - |b|^2}. 
$$
$A$ will be normal if and only if all the above entries are zero.  In particular, we see that this means that $A$ is normal if and only if
$$
|c| = |b|, \quad -b \bar a + a \bar c + b \bar d - d \bar c = 0.
$$
In order to take advantage of the first equation, write $b,c$ in polar form.  That is, let's say
$$
b = r_1e^{i\theta}, \quad c = r_1e^{i \phi}
$$
where $r_1 \geq 0$ and $\theta,\phi \in \Bbb R$.  Substituting these into the second equation yields
$$
- r_1e^{i \theta}\bar a + a r_1e^{-i\phi} + re^{i\theta} \bar d - d r_1e^{-i\phi} = 0 \implies\\
e^{i \theta}[\bar d-\bar a] + e^{-i \phi}[a-d] = 0 \implies\\
e^{i \theta}[\overline{d-a}] - e^{-i \phi}[d-a] = 0 \implies\\
e^{i (\theta + \phi)}[\overline{d-a}] - [d-a] = 0.
$$
Write $d-a$ in polar form.  That is, take $d-a = r_2 e^{i \psi}$. We can write the above as the equation
$$
e^{i (\theta + \phi)}r_2 e^{-i\psi} - r_2e^{i\psi} = 0 \implies\\
e^{i(\theta + \phi - \psi)} = e^{i \psi} \implies\\
e^{i(\theta + \phi)} = [e^{i \psi}]^2 \implies\\
\pm \exp\left[i\frac{\theta + \phi}2\right] = e^{i \psi} = \frac{d-a}{r_2} \implies\\
d-a = \pm r_2 \exp\left[i\frac{\theta + \phi}2\right].
$$

---

The above analysis leads to the following parameterization of the normal matrices.  Select any $a \in \Bbb C$, $r_1,r_2 \geq 0$ and angles $\phi,\psi$.  The matrix with this value of $a$ and
$$
b = r_1e^{i\theta}, \quad 
c = r_1e^{i \phi}, \quad 
d = a \pm r_2 \exp\left[i\frac{\theta + \phi}2\right]
$$
is necessarily normal, and every normal matrix can be written in this way.  We could also tweak some definition to get the equivalent parameterization
$$
a,b = [\text{arbitrary complex}], \quad 
c = b e^{2i k_1}, \quad 
d = a + k_2 e^{i k_1}
$$
where $k_1,k_2$ are real. This amounts to
$$
A = aI + \pmatrix{0&b\\b e^{2i k_1} & k_2 e^{ik_1}}.
$$

---

As far as the second part goes: it suffices to take a multiple of a unitary matrix.  For instance, take the matrix of any rotation by an angle that is not a multiple of $\pi/2$, and multiply it by some $\alpha > 1$.

Alternatively: for any normal $A$, there exists a $\gamma \in \Bbb C$ such that $A + \gamma I$ is neither unitary, Hermitian, nor skew-Hermitian.  To see that this is the case, it suffices to look at the expressions for $M^*M$ and $M \pm M^*$, where $M = A + \gamma$ (in terms of $A$ and $\gamma$, not in terms of the entries).

Alternatively: note that every diagonal matrix is normal. However, not every diagonal matrix is Hermitian, skew-Hermitian, or unitary.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a slightly different take on the other answer.

Start by noticing that the identity component of $A$ doesn't affect it being normal, that is, if $A=\alpha I+\tilde A$ with $\tilde A$ traceless, then $A$ is normal *iff* $\tilde A$ is. We can thus assume without loss of generality $A$ to be traceless, and write it as
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} z & b \\ c & -z\end{pmatrix},\qquad z,b,c\in\mathbb C.$$
The normality condition, $AA^\dagger=A^\dagger A$, translates into the following two conditions on the parameters:
$$
\begin{cases}|b|=|c|, \\ c\bar z=z \bar b.\end{cases}
$$
Writing the polar representations of the parameters as $z=r_z e^{i\varphi_z}, b=r_b e^{i\varphi_b}$, $c=r_c e^{i\varphi_c}$.

1. Assuming $z\neq0$: these conditions amount to $r_b=r_c$
   and $\varphi_c +\varphi_b = 2\varphi_z$. It follows that the generic form of a normal 2x2 complex matrix is
   $$
   A=\alpha I + \begin{pmatrix} r_z e^{i(\varphi_b+\varphi_c)/2} & r_b e^{i\varphi_b}\\ r_b e^{i\varphi_c}& -r_z e^{i(\varphi_b+\varphi_c)/2}\end{pmatrix},
   $$
   for any $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ and $r_z,r_b,\varphi_b,\varphi_c\in\mathbb R$.
   We can further simplify this assuming $\varphi_z=0$ (which amounts to collecting a global phase for the matrix). We then get the general solution
   $$
   A=\alpha I + e^{i\varphi_z}\begin{pmatrix} r_z & r_b e^{i\varphi_b}\\ r_b e^{-i\varphi_b}& -r_z\end{pmatrix},
   $$
   for all $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ and $r_z,r_b,\varphi_b,\varphi_z\in\mathbb R$.
2. For $z=0$, the only constraint is $|b|=|c|$. The general solution is thus
   $$A = \alpha I +\begin{pmatrix}0 & b e^{i\varphi} \\ b & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
   for any $\alpha,b\in\mathbb C$ and $\varphi\in\mathbb R$.