# Determine all real $2 \times 2$ matrices that commute with their transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, symmetric-matrices

Determine all real $2 \times 2$ matrices

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    c & d  
  \end{bmatrix}$

that commute with $A^T$:

$$A \cdot A^T = A^T \cdot A$$

---

A matrix commutes with its transpose if it is a symmetric or normal matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    c & d  
  \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    c & d  
  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + c^2 & ab + cd  \\
    ab + cd & b^2 + d^2  
  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    c & d  
  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    c & d  
  \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 + b^2 & ac + bd  \\
    ac + bd & c^2 + d^2  
  \end{bmatrix}$$

To be equal, either $b=c$ or $b = -c$. If $b = -c$  then we must have $a = d$. So we have either

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    b & d  
  \end{bmatrix} $$ or $$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b   \\
    -b & a  
  \end{bmatrix} $$

Those are all the real $2 \times 2$ matrices that commute with their transpose

---

Is this correct ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513736/how-to-determine-all-2-times-2-normal-matrices

Comment: @Asinomás Yes, I saw this question and the matrice there is complex valued while mine is real valued

Comment: your solution looks good to me, and it coincides with the solution in the other question.